# Command "make:factory" is not defined

Tags: laravel-5

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "make:factory" is not defined.

php artisan make:factory PostFactory

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "make:factory" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have old versions of PHP and / or Laravel. Try upgrading with the following command:

```
$ composer update
```

Comment: Thanks to giving the valuable suggestion

Comment: @JoyantaJoy Instead of proposing changes to peoples answers, it's usually better to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56317559/edit) your question. Is "_Okay i changed my xampp_" the solution to your original question?

Answer (score 1):

what i did is :

to remove composer.lock
then

```
composer remove maker
composer remove zenstruck/foundry
```

then

```
composer require maker ---dev
composer require zenstruck/foundry --dev
composer update
```